# Problem Mesh Renderer in Unity

Tags: rendering, bones, unity

I have a simple Object and one armature (1 bones).

[image]

In Unity, object have a Mesh renderer like this :
[image]

WIth a Ctrl/P, I set the object's parenting to armature
[image]

In Unity, a black zone appears and a Skinned mesh renderer 
replaces the Mesh Renderer.
[image]

Comment: are you sure there are not two copies of the object in Unity? Looks like a second copy overlaying the first.

Comment: I realized that object and armature did not have the same origin. When I set same origin two both, texture's back to normal. Thanks for your answer.